# Laravel5.3でのConfig設定について

Tags: laravel-5

いつもお世話になっています。

Laravel Framework version 5.3を利用してLaravelの勉強をしています。

各所で使い回す定数や配列を1箇所に纏めたいと思い、色々と調べて以下の手順を踏んだのですが、設定の読み込みができません。

以下のファイルを新規作成
/config/const.php

中身は単純に以下の通りです。

```
<?php
return [
  "hoge" => "fuga",
];
```

Controller側で以下のように取り出してみたのですが、

```
$value = Config::get('const.hoge');
echo $value;
```

以下のようにエラーが出ます。

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\xxxxx\Config' not found
```

そこで、

```
use Config;
```

を追加したところ、エラーは表示されなくなったのですが、肝心の設定がecho表示されません。
（真っ白です。$valueをis_nullで確認してもnullでした）

config/app.phpには

```
'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
```

と記載されているので、場所がおかしいのでは…と思ったのですが、あまりベースのファイル軍に加えたくはありませんし、調べる先々で「configの下に追加で設定可能」と書いてあったので、/config/const.php内で設定できるなら、そのようにしたいです。

/config/const.php内は

```
<?php
return array(
  'hoge' => 'fuga'
);
```

の書き方を試しても駄目で、Controller側で、

```
$value = Config:get('const.hoge');
$value = Config:get('const');
```

のように試してみても駄目でした。

どのようにすれば読み込むことが出来るのでしょうか？

Comment: configのキャッシュ(`artisan config:cache`)が存在していたりしませんか？もしその可能性があれば `artisan config:clear` をしてみてください。

Comment: hinaloeさん キャッシュの可能性は考えてphp artisan cache:clearはしていたのですが、configは別にコマンドがあるんですね。勉強になりました。大変助かりました。ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

LaravelのConfigurationでは、ヘルパ関数も使えます。(ドキュメントを読んだだけですので、確認はしていませんが）

```
$value = config('const.hoge');
```

また、Laravel5.3でファサードを使うのでしたら、`use Config;`ではなく、

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
```

とするのがよいそうです。